# SQL String syntax error in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have this SQL string

```
theSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_PROJECTS (co_id, contact_id, prop_id, worktype_id, incharge_id, project_name, project_ref," _
    & "project_status, project_awardref, project_awarddate, project_startdate, project_targetdate," _
    & "project_completedate, project_finalreportdate, project_location, project_notes)"

theSQL = theSQL & " VALUES (" & theCoID & "," & theContactID & "," & thePropID & "," & theWorkTypeID & "," & theInCharge & "," _
      & "'" & theProjectName & "'" & "," & theProjectRef & "," & theProjectStatus & "," & theAwardRef _
      & theAwardDate & "," & theStartDate & "," & theTargetDate & "," & theCompleteDate & "," & theFinalReportDate & "," _
      & theLocation & "," & theNotes & ")"
```

When I do `DoCmd.RunSQL (theSQL)` I get syntax error (runtime error 3134).

I sent the output to `Debug.Print`. Can't find what is wrong with the syntax.

Anyone who can tell what is wrong with this sql command from VBA?

Some variables are null like `thetargetdate` and `thecompletedate` and I did not include the `projectID` in this query because it is autonumber. I want the number generated automatically.

Is it not allowed to pass null value to SQL?

Thanks

**DEBUG PRINT RESULT :**

```
 INSERT INTO tbl_PROJECTS (co_id, contact_id, prop_id, worktype_id,
 incharge_id, project_name, project_ref, project_status,
 project_awardref, project_awarddate, project_startdate,
 project_targetdate, project_completedate, project_finalreportdate,
 project_location, project_notes) VALUES (61,66,134,1,1,'STRUCTURAL
 DESIGN',,AWARDED,Test LPO,2/11/2016,,,,,Dnata 4 storey warehouse,)
```

Comment: What does `Debug.Print theSQL` show you?

Comment: Please read this blog post before continuing down your current path as what you're doing is a security risk. http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-sql.html

Comment: @HansUp, I added debug print output

Comment: you need quotes around string and date values: `AWARDED`,`Test LPO`, `2/11/2016`, `Dnata 4 storey warehouse Alquoz`

Comment: You're also missing a comma at the end of the second row of your SQL (after `theAwardRef`.  Please STRONGLY consider changing to parameters - you avoid these types of mistakes and reduce the risk of SQL injection.

Comment: @DStanley Can you elaborate on "changing to parameters". I'm new to SQL but like to start on the right side.

Comment: @PaulHunt, thanks for the link. reading it now

Comment: @Wayne [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql%20parameters%20access%20vba) should give you lots of good resources.

Comment: @Wayne It was useful to show us what `theSQL` contains --- doing that got quick responses pointing out the flaws in the `INSERT` statement.  You could spend your time fixing those, but I think you would be better off to switch to a parameter query as the others advised or use `DAO.Recordset.Add`  With either of those you would not be bothered by issues such as quote needed here but not there ... and so forth.

Comment: @HansUp, thanks for that. I actually was using DAO.Recordset.Add but I thought familiarizing myself using SQL. Reading at the comments and seeing the security risk using SQL by a non experience coder, looks like I have to go back to DAO. Thanks for the headsUp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it not allowed to pass null value to SQL?

It is, but it can't be done by stating a space. You must write Null:

```
VALUES (61,66,134,1,1,'STRUCTURAL DESIGN',Null,'AWARDED','Test LPO',#2/11/2016#,Null,Null,Null,Null,'Dnata 4 storey warehouse Alquoz',Null)
```

and quotes and date delimiters are missing.

Comment: Though I will not continue to this path as others have suggested. Good to know the proper syntax for it.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You wrote this:

```
theSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_PROJECTS (co_id, contact_id, prop_id, worktype_id, incharge_id, project_name, project_ref," _
    & "project_status, project_awardref, project_awarddate, project_startdate, project_targetdate," _
    & "project_completedate, project_finalreportdate, project_location, project_notes)"

theSQL = theSQL & " VALUES (" & theCoID & "," & theContactID & "," & thePropID & "," & theWorkTypeID & "," & theInCharge & "," _
      & "'" & theProjectName & "'" & "," & theProjectRef & "," & theProjectStatus & "," & theAwardRef _
      & theAwardDate & "," & theStartDate & "," & theTargetDate & "," & theCompleteDate & "," & theFinalReportDate & "," _
      & theLocation & "," & theNotes & ")"
```

In the second line in the second block, there's no ending quotes.